# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

When Trying to return a response it is throwing below error.

I don't have ResponseImpl class so the solution of using @jsonIgnore annotation doesnt work for me.

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl["location"])

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to ignore null fields in the "ResponseImpl" object to be not passed further to the client?

Comment: Yes but the problem is i don't see ResponseImpl class in my code.

Comment: @marcin.programuje pls do help.

Comment: Please put the fragment of your code that throws an error.

Comment: @marcin.programuje Thanks for your helping approach.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

I was using Response type earlier and was getting that error.

I changed Response type to ResponseEntity and instead of returning Response object i returned ResponseEntity. And added @Producess annotation too.

return ResponseEntity
.ok()
.body(response.getEntity());